# kotlinx decodeFromString to 'ArrayList' vs 'CustomClass extending ArrayList'

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist, kotlinx.serialization

Why does this work:

```
val string = "[1, 2, 3]"
val result: ArrayList<Int> = json.decodeFromString(string)
```

but this doesn't:

```
@Serializable
class MyClass : ArrayList<Int>()

val string = "[1, 2, 3]"
val myClass: MyClass = json.decodeFromString("string")
```

throws this error:

```
Expected start of the object '{', but had 'EOF' instead
```

`MyClass` is also an `ArrayList` so I'm unsure why it doesn't work

Comment: Serialization framework can't know how to deserialize your custom `MyClass`. `ArrayList` is a specific case that is automatically supported, but any custom class needs a custom way to deserialize it. And `@Serializable` provides serializer that stores objects as maps, not lists.

Comment: Also an ``ArrayList`` isn't a ``MyClass`` so you can't just assign one to a ``MyClass`` variable, in the same way that if a function provides a ``Number`` you can't just assign it to an ``Int`` (but if it provides an ``Int`` you can assign that to a ``Number`` reference). You could make it a ``typealias`` instead of a class though, if your class has nothing else going on in it